# Strange Design Problems With Infragistics Controls

Tags: winforms, infragistics

I'm working on an existing WinForms application and I am having some weird issues with Infragistics controls in a WinForms app.

When I open a form or usercontrol in the project that has Infragistics controls on it, it looks like 
this http://sdrv.ms/S7gvmS

I cannot access any of the controls in the design surface. Clicking does nothing. And, all of the controls appear in the lower area.

So I created a new test solution and dropped some Infragisstics controls on and got this http://sdrv.ms/SRdo2y

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Seems like the Form designer doesn't recognize your form as a control container. Missing  `private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components` and its initialization code?

Comment: I see "private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null" at the top of all the controls and forms that I open.Truth is, I don't really know what's going on. I posted a msg to Infragistics forum, and the tech wrote back "if I have to make a guess here, I would say that you have the first project referencing DLLs which are not in the Global Assembly Cache of your machine".

Comment: If you open, in the failing project, the csproj file with a normal text editor (I suppose a C# project here but should be the similar with vb.net) do you see the same references as in the working project (As an example in a project of mine I have this reference line `    <Reference Include="Infragistics4.Win.Misc.v11.2, Version=11.2.20112.2050, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb, processorArchitecture=MSIL">`

Comment: Have you checked the references to see what the version of the Infragistics assemblies are for both the project with the issue and the project that you created new?  If they are different, then the guess posted to the Infragistics forums is most likely correct and you will need to update the references in the existing project or get the appropriate service release.

Comment: Figured it out... It was just that.. The version of the assemblies was wrong.

Comment: There are so many differents issues with Infragistics control at design time with differents workarounds. It is very hard to sum up all of them. The most trivial is the inability to open a control or a form in design mode unless I restart Visual Studio. The worse I have to cope with is design data loss. I am sick to report bugs in the forum so I ended commiting frequently to the source control software I use.

Comment: The links you posted have expired. This is why SO discourages posting links in questions.

Answer (score 1):

When I've run in to similar issues before it's tended to be a license or version problem, the Infragistics libraries contain code stopping them working at design-time if a valid license isn't installed. To resolve this, I'd first recommend deleting all of the *.licx files in your solution. These can be easily corrupted especially if you're using source control and should be regenerated correctly when you go in at design time. If that fails, then I'd try uninstalling and reinstalling Infragistics ensuring the version installed matches those of your projects' reference.

P.S. Realise this is far too late to help the original poster but hopefully will help people coming across similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when Visual Studio cannot find the Design assembly. The components refer to a designer and if Visual Studio cannot find the designer, it makes the assumption that the object is a component instead of a control and places it in the system tray.

Typically, this indicates that something when wrong with your installation of the components, so the usual solution is to re-install.