# Cannot select Infragistics controls in WinForms designer

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, infragistics

I just upgraded the Infragistics controls on a project from 2006 to 2011.

Now, if I open the designer for a form containing any Infragistics controls, the Infragistics controls appear in a separate panel underneath the form designer, and I am unable to select their counterparts in the design view.

If I click on an Infragistics control in the designer, it select the container control instead.

[image]

However, if I click the control in the lower panel, I can still edit the properties, and Visual Studio recognizes it as a UltraCombo. Also, the controls all still appear in the Toolbox, but if I try to add a new one to the form, it goes to the lower panel.

[image]

My coworker installed the new version of Infragistics on his computer and got my latest changes from source control, and he does not have the issue.

My issue sounds similar to this question [Strange Design Problems With Infragistics Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605572/strange-design-problems-with-infragistics-controls)  however the OPs reference material is no longer available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question since I fixed it before submitting the questions to SO.

In short, it was my project references...

I decided to check out my project references as mentioned in the other question. I was pointing to copies of the DLLs that were not in the GAC. I changed the references to point to the GAC and all was well.

The reason I was pointing to non-GAC DLLs is: I like to keep DLLs in a source controlled "lib" folder that is in the same folder structure as the project. That way other developers can just grab the latest and they have all the correct versions of the DLLs that they need for the project and don't have to worry about installing them just to do a minor build. Apparently, the Infragistics library does not like that. My guess is it has to do with licensing. It's strange though, my computer was licensed, but the non-GAC DLLs didn't work.

Comment: If the versions between what you have referenced and what is in your GAC is different it could cause this issue as the designers for the NetAdvantage controls in your GAC wouldn't match the version of the toolset that you are referencing.

Comment: I had multiple versions in the GAC (not all our projects are updated). The version I was referencing was in the GAC. I also copied the DLLs to my "lib" folder, and I was referencing them. To be honest, I'd be glad to get rid of Infragistics.

Comment: Do all of the versions in your GAC also have the design assemblies in the GAC?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all Infragistics dlls referenced by your projects need to come from Infragistics installation folder, due some license restrictions.

Since I am using version 2019.2 in my case the folder is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Infragistics\2019.2\Windows Forms\CLR4.0\Bin

To make it work for you:

1. Make sure you have installed:

- Infragistics_WinForms_20192.msi
- Infragistics_VersionUtility_20192.msi

2. Run Infragistic Version Utility, select your solution, and run the tool (make sure you have removed ReadOnly attribute from all files in your solution folder, otherwise you my face some issues)

And you're done. All controls can be selected and edited now.
[image]