# Can't select controls on my form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

This has started happening recently (not too sure what caused the change unfortunately), but I can no longer select controls on my form.  My reading on this has uncovered some possible explanations including:

1. You're running your program in debug mode
2. Your form is derived from another class where everything is private
3. Your controls are "locked".

For (1), no, it's definitely not running and for (2) my form is derived from DevComponents.DotNetBar.RibbonForm.  For (3), no, they're not "locked" (I tried locking and then unlocking, in case some state was stuck in the designer, but no dice).  The controls are on my form, not the base class form and the instances aren't private (I deliberately made them public just to test this one) and they were working fine before.

So, what can I do?  I can select a control, like a ComboBox, from the Properties window drop-down list, change its properties and so on.  But when I choose it nothing gets selected in the designer. I can select the form itself (by its border) and resize it in the designer. I can add a new control, like a label, and interact with it fine in the designer, so this is something that's happened to my existing controls.

I'm sure it's either something spectacularly dumb, or Visual Studio 2012 is on the wind-up.

Anybody?

Edit:  Zipped the solution up and brought it home.  Cleaned and rebuilt and it's working fine in the designer.  I guess there's an issue with my install at work, somehow.

Comment: If you make a new winforms application and add a control to it, can you select this control?

Comment: Yes.  As I pointed out, I can add new controls to this form and manipulate them fine.  It's just the existing controls that seem somehow "locked", even though the form isn't and there's no little padlocks all over it.

Comment: Hmm.. is there any common property set for all of them when you Ctrl + A?

Comment: Good call, but when I do that, the Lock item in the format menu is disabled.

Comment: There are various ways to break the designer by having events in your control(s) that also run at design-time.  You are supposed to use the DesignMode property to avoid such a mishap.  Very hard to guess what you could have done to break the selection logic, use source control to review the changes you've made.

Comment: Well, good point Hans.  I went through EVERY single event and added code to just return if it's Design Mode, rebuilt and still, nothing can be selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I kind-of solved the problem, although I don't know what the actual cause was.  In my program I'm referencing devcomponents.dotnetbar dll.  I removed the reference and then re-added it, rebuilt the program and now everything's working in the designer as it should.

Answer (score 8):

The problem can occur when a new version of DevComponents.DotNetBar is installed and  the old version is still referenced from a separate library folder.

The app and all DotNetBar referenced dlls should be re-referenced to the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

This problem's main reason is because of older versions of components being used in a project and a newer version of the component has been installed on the machine.  9 times out of 10, the project is still pointed to the component in the GAC.  Remove the reference to the component and re-add it from the newly installed component's location and all should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with DotnetBar, resolved it by adding the reference DevComponents.DotNetBar.Design.DLL in the project

Comment: Any ideas on where that dll is, i can see it in the gac but in the latest version of DotNetBar its not obvious where the 'DevComponents.DotNetBar.Design.DLL' is.

Comment: Wouldn't you then have to ship the Design DLL with your executable?  that would be a really bad idea, and probably not permitted under the DotNetBar license

Answer (score 2):

Just right-click the form and uncheck `Lock Controls`.

Comment: Yea, been there too.  Should have put it in my list.

Comment: @Sayse Yeah, it's like when you `Print Screen` its Desktop, hide the icons, and set the print screen to be a background.

Comment: @Robinson I can reproduce all your problems with `Lock Controls`, sorry that this is not helping you.

Comment: Yes Nemanja, however the designer doesn't "think" they're locked in the UI it presents me.

Comment: That locks/unlocks the main form only.  It works fine as you could expect.  Doesn't have an affect on the controls on the form, however.

Answer (score 2):

Resetting the Toolbox (Right click inside Toolbox) and then "reinstalling" the new toolbars did the trick for me.  Seems to be a bug in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation but Closing and Re-Opening my project solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after moving a project to another PC. I didn't install DotNetBar on the new machine and just copied the DevComponents.DotNetBar.dll. I resolved it by also copying **DevComponents.DotNetBar.Design.dll** (contained in the old machine's DotNetBar installation directory) to the new machine and referencing it in the project.

Comment: thanks you very much my firend .. your answer was great beacuse after some hours , I could finally resolve the problem ...

Answer (score 2):

The *general* issue is using references that no longer exist.  For me, I had several versions of Infragistics controls and uninstalled all but the latest version.  At least one of my references pointed to a DLL that didn't exist.  Therefore, the seeming removal and re-adding essentially pointed the references to the correct (or present) DLLs.

Also, one of the *symptoms* of this problem is that the labels for the controls appears in a window below the dialog/form.

Answer (score 2):

To get this working for me I ended up having to add the references to the designer for the different controls: `SuperGrid.Design` and `DotNetBar.Design`

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem, and it was caused after I wrongfully played around with my "using" and "namespaces" in a blind attempt to get rid of an error.  I saved each .cs file one by one and then closed VS and re-opened it.  Presto, the little locks vanished.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, you can `ctrl+a` to select all, then move the `controls` to somewhere, doesn't matter where. Now you will be able to `select` them again seperately.

I got this problem by dragging a `tab` down so i could see two `codes` at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but in case it helps someone else, my version of this problem was an inability to select controls on a tab page.   Sending the tab page to the back didn't help.  But I found I could get the controls highlighted by selecting them in the properties box and then placing the mouse over the control sizing arrows and right clicking, I could then bring the controls forward.

Answer (score 1):

Just Closing the current Soln and Opening again solves this problem,
This might have caused because of some hidden selections in other forms!

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was only with "Send to Back" and "Bring to Front"

I did Control+A then deselected every other control, then right clicked on the controls i was not able to see before and just clicked "Bring To Front".

For me the issue happened because i removed those controls from Group Box.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2019, I close the form, and any files currently open that are associated with that form (.cs .rex) and then reopen them. This solved my 'not being able to select a control' problem. I find this problem occurs occasionally, and is a bit of a nuisance, but this simple fix always seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into another variation on this theme. I'd placed Infragistics controls into a lib folder. The project would still compile/run, but for the controls to be selectable in the editor the project must reference the original installed controls. See [Cannot select Infragistics controls in WinForms designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320746/cannot-select-infragistics-controls-in-winforms-designer) for more details.