# Adding blank form to one project in solution. They auto-intherhit

Tags: c#, winforms, dll-injection

In our Company we use `C# 4.0,VS2010 and DotNetBar.`
Now I am working in a big concern. I have a simple task to do, but...
When add new `WinForms` blank dialog to one of projects in solution. They create with content and I cant do anything with it.

[image: New blank window in project]

This project do not have changes in three years and now. Me newbiest programmer must resolve this problem. Anybody in this small company know how to.
I try add and remove references , try copy empty window from other project in this solution and then i cant change name of button...

My wish is to resolve this issue and understand. I read all day and I have a suspicion it might be a `DLL Injection`. But when, where. Why at the stage of project design.

I do not know. Please help me.

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768052/cant-select-controls-on-my-form.  Also might want to contact the DevComponents support.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can occur when a new version of DevComponents.DotNetBar is installed and the old version is still referenced from a separate library folder.

The app and all DotNetBar referenced dlls should be re-referenced to the latest version.