# Using local copy of an infragistics DLL vs the copy in the GAC

Tags: c#, dll, infragistics, gac

we are using the infragistics libraries for a long time now. But now we ran into a problem, that has been solved here [Cannot select Infragistics controls in winform designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320746/cannot-select-infragistics-controls-in-winform-designer).

My more specific question now is, why does this problem not occur on all of our colleaques computers, but only on mine? We have the same visual studio solution and all of the source code is from a subversion repository.

We decided to put a copy of the infragistics dlls to our controls directory in the project, so we can deploy it later on very easily by copy and paste the files into the target directory (but still we need a setup tool to install for the first time).

How can we make sure, that the following requirements (useful or not) are met?

- Updating the application still possible by copy&paste.
- developper tracks the needed infragistic dlls by copying them into the controls directory (that is then copied into the application executable directory).
- the problem from the link above doesnt occur

Perhaps we miss something important?

- Is it bad practice to update the application by simply copying newer files to the application directory? Or is it even "illegal" in some way?
- Do the infragistics tools **need** to be installed via setup or msi installer? Or is it sufficient to copy them?

[edit #1]:

to clarify things, as i know whats going wrong (see the link above) and what the possible solution is, i need some good arguments for or against not using the controls directory with respect to our practice of deploying the application without setup when it gets updated. We need to give our customer the posibility to update our application without a setup, because in his factory he needs to update a couple of computers at once, and if he is able to do this without the need of a setup, it will be more cost efficient compared to a setup way.

Comment: Some DLLs need to be registered using regsvr32, which is something installers typically take care of. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: The way you hacked yourself out of trouble is an extraordinary bad practice.  You can never assume that the GAC has the proper assemblies available.  Building a program must always be done with *reference assemblies*.  Like you do with the .NET framework assemblies for example, stored in c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies.  If the vendor's installer doesn't provide them then you must create them, make your own copy in a well-known location.   Then also check them into source control so you can still build a year or two from now.

Comment: @Hans Passant: By using the controls directory in our solution folder, we thought to have it the right way. But as it seems (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320746/cannot-select-infragistics-controls-in-winform-designer), this leads to some unexpected behaviour. I had the same problem, but my colleaques dont have them.

Comment: Did you use the tool provided by Infragistics to update your projects? Also is your _controls directory_ local to each PC? Referencing a fixed DRIVE+LOCATION could cause problems to other PC and viceversa

Comment: As i am not the main developper of the project i dont know if the tool was used, but the second remark is not a question  - we all use the same directory structure on our project drives and directories.

Comment: For the designers to work correctly each developer should install the Infragistics toolset locally on their machine and it is important that the same service release be installed by everyone.  This would put the design assembly in the GAC so the designers can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my two cents:

- Try setting all Infragistics libraries Copy Local property to True.
  This will copy the dll to the bin folder each time you build your
  application. This could solve the problem you are having with
  updating the application by copy&paste;
- It is better each developer to install the libraries into the GAC. I suppose all of you are using the same version of these libraries.
  Otherwise, it will be real chaos. If, for some reason, you are not using same versions try to set for each Infragistics dll Specific Version to False
- If all the controls are appear in the Component try (down in the designer) this clearly shows, that Designer.dll is broken or is not found. So it is always good idea to install the dlls into GAC - this should add the Infragistics Designer dll there too, and you should not have this problem.

So, install everything into GAC, set Copy Local to true and set Specific Version to false.

Also whenever you need to upgrade project containing Infragistics libraries use their nice tool [Version Utility](http://help.infragistics.com/Doc/WinForms/current/CLR4.0/?page=Win_Upgrading_a_Project_to_Infragistics_Windows_Forms_11.1_(and_above)_Using_Version_Utility.html) - this could save you many efforts

Comment: First point is no problem right now. Only the dev has a problem. Second point we install always the same version for all devs. Third point sounds reasonably good - as using the local copy of the dll instead of the gac copy could ommit the designer dll. I think your answer seems to answer my question best so far now

Comment: I would recommend against setting Specific Version to False on the references as this could cause confusion if one developer is on a different version as two developers could see different behavior locally while running the same source and you may not realize that you are actually using different versions of the Infragistics toolset.